# Detecting whether a headset is plugged into an Android device or not.

Tags: android, audio, android-intent

How can I determine whether a headset is plugged into an Android device or not?

Comment: I am developing an Application... And i need to know it for sure....User can cheat also if i prompt him the question

Comment: I edited your question, if its not what you want to ask, please correct it.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

When you say "headset", do you mean "wired headset"? If so, there's an intent to detect whether or not one is being plugged or unplugged: `ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG`.

To check the status, you can use `AudioManager.isWiredHeadsetOn()`, although that may return false if there is also a bluetooth headset, and audio is routed to that instead.

Comment: Hello Mike, What should i do if some one use a Blutooth headset?

Comment: AudioManager.isWiredHeadsetOn() always seems to return false (tested on several Gingerbread devices), whether or not a headset is plugged in. If you can provide a working code example, that would be great.

Comment: @ChadSchultz You need to add permission MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS in manifest..then only it will return correct status.

Comment: is deprecated function API21

Comment: For Bluetooth headsets see jobbert's answer here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4715865/how-to-programmatically-tell-if-a-bluetooth-device-is-connected-android-2-2

Answer (score 50):

You can use the broadcast receiver.

So, You might write this code in "AndroidManifest.xml"

```
<receiver android:name="com.juno.brheadset.HeadsetStateReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.HEADSET_PLUG"/>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>-->
```

But, This doesn't work. When OS send this "HEADSET_PLUG" intent, OS set the flag "Intent.FLAG_RECEIVER_REGISTERED_ONLY" So, You should write the code like below in Activity or Service class instead of "AndroidManifest" things.

```
public class BRHeadsetActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    IntentFilter receiverFilter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG);
    HeadsetStateReceiver receiver = new HeadsetStateReceiver();
    registerReceiver( receiver, receiverFilter );


}
```

I hope this article help you. Bye!

This is the part of "HeadsetObserver.java", Android SDK Source.

```
private final void sendIntent(int headset, int headsetState, int prevHeadsetState, String headsetName) {
    if ((headsetState & headset) != (prevHeadsetState & headset)) {
        //  Pack up the values and broadcast them to everyone
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG);

        **intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_RECEIVER_REGISTERED_ONLY);**

        int state = 0;
        int microphone = 0;

        if ((headset & HEADSETS_WITH_MIC) != 0) {
            microphone = 1;
        }
        if ((headsetState & headset) != 0) {
            state = 1;
        }
        intent.putExtra("state", state);
        intent.putExtra("name", headsetName);
        intent.putExtra("microphone", microphone);

        if (LOG) Slog.v(TAG, "Intent.ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG: state: "+state+" name: "+headsetName+" mic: "+microphone);
        // TODO: Should we require a permission?
        ActivityManagerNative.broadcastStickyIntent(intent, null);
    }
}
```

Comment: @Sumit  So sorry. I saw your replay now. What about my code can I explain for you? :)

Comment: @Sumit Ok. I think you don't understand this. If you add "FLAG_RECEIVER_REGISTERED_ONLY" to intent for broadcasting, I can receive your broadcasting when only I do "registerReceiver(...)" on code not on 'AndroidManifest.xml'.

Comment: What is "HeadsetStateReceiver" is that an SDK class or a custom class?

Comment: @shim it's a custom class and it extends BroadcastReceiver and have a method onReceive

Comment: Curious, why do you have to say bye?

Answer (score 18):

`AudioManager.isWiredHeadsetOn()` always return `false` because it requires user-permission `MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS`.

I spent several days while found answer. There are no info about this in official documentation. And this `bug` already registered in `BugTracker`.

Answer (score 4):

This should help you : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG

Answer (score 2):

You can create this kind of receiver class (Kotlin with Flow) in your project:

```
class HeadsetPlugReceiver : BroadcastReceiver() {

    private val _isPlugged = MutableStateFlow<Boolean>(false)
    val isPlugged: StateFlow<Boolean> = _isPlugged.asStateFlow()

    override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
        context.appComponent.inject(this)
        val action = intent.action
        Log.i(TAG, "onReceive: $action")
        when (action) {
            Intent.ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG -> sendEvent(intent)
            else -> checkStateOff(intent)
        }
    }

    private fun checkStateOff(intent: Intent) {
       Log.i(TAG, "onReceive: the local Bluetooth adapter is off")
    }

    private fun sendEvent(intent: Intent) {
        val isPlugged = intent.getIntExtra(HEADSET_STATE, 0) == 1
        Log.i(TAG, "sendEvent: $isPlugged")
        _isPlugged.value = isPlugged
    }

    private companion object {

       private const val TAG = "HeadsetPlugReceiver"
       // Headset constant
       private const val HEADSET_STATE = "state"
    }
}
```

then register this receiver in some class with context:

```
val headsetReceiver = HeadsetPlugReceiver()
val headsetFilter = IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG)
    context.registerReceiver(headsetReceiver, headsetFilter)
```

then collect `isPlugged` and you get the state of your wire headset connecting state

PS: don't forget to unregister your receiver when it no needs `context.unregisterReceiver(headsetReceiver)`

Comment: How exactly is `context.appComponent.inject(this)` supposed to work?

Comment: it needs for Dagger 2.  Can be ignored in this case

Answer (score 1):

First , create receiver in your manifest:

```
    <receiver android:name="com.yourapplication.BroadcastReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.HEADSET_PLUG"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

don't forget to change com.yourapplication according to your project name

Create two variables in the head of your activity :

```
private  BroadcastReceiver mReceiver  ;
boolean Microphone_Plugged_in = false;
```

Define your receiver inside onCreate of your activity :

```
        mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            final String action = intent.getAction();
            int iii=2;
            if (Intent.ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG.equals(action)) {
                iii=intent.getIntExtra("state", -1);
                if(Integer.valueOf(iii)==0){
                    Microphone_Plugged_in = false;
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"microphone not plugged in",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }if(Integer.valueOf(iii)==1){
                    Microphone_Plugged_in = true;
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"microphone plugged in",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        }};
        IntentFilter receiverFilter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG);
        registerReceiver( mReceiver, receiverFilter );
```

add onResume and onStope :

```
@Override
  protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG);
    getApplicationContext().registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    getApplicationContext().unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To add to the other answers, from Android documentation:

> Warning: Limit how many broadcast receivers you set in your app.
> Having too many broadcast receivers can affect your app's performance
> and the battery life of users' devices. For more information about
> APIs you can use instead of the BroadcastReceiver class for scheduling
> background work, see Background Optimizations.

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/receiver-element

Which means that you should create a small number of broadcast receivers as possible, to prevent memory issues with your app.

I will suggest using a singleton class with this receiver. In Kotlin:

```
class HeadsetReceiver private constructor(): BroadcastReceiver() {

    // instances
    var callback: HeadsetReceiverCallback? = null

    //region singleton
    private object HOLDER {
        val INSTANCE = HeadsetReceiver()
    }

    companion object {
        val instance: HeadsetReceiver by lazy { HOLDER.INSTANCE }
    }
    //endregion

    override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
        if (intent.action == Intent.ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG) {
            if(intent.getIntExtra("state", -1) == 0) {
                callback?.onHeadsetDisconnected()
            } else {
                callback?.onHeadsetConnected()
            }
        }
    }

    fun register(context: Context) {
        val receiverFilter = IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG)
        context.registerReceiver(this, receiverFilter)
    }

    fun unregister(context: Context) {
        context.unregisterReceiver(this)
        callback = null
    }

    interface HeadsetReceiverCallback {
        fun onHeadsetConnected()
        fun onHeadsetDisconnected()
    }
}
```

Register:

```
HeadsetReceiver.instance.register(context)
        HeadsetReceiver.instance.callback = object : HeadsetReceiver.HeadsetReceiverCallback {
            override fun onHeadsetConnected() {
                println("connected!")
            }

            override fun onHeadsetDisconnected() {
                println("disonnected!")
            }
        }
```

Unregister:

```
HeadsetReceiver.instance.unregister(context)
```