# Listening for AUX connection

Tags: android, android-intent

Is there any way to know if AUX cable is connected in Android?

Comment: Possible duplicate of :

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6249023/detecting-whether-a-headset-is-plugged-in-or-not

Answer (score 1):

Are you talking about the audio out? Because if so I think [this is what you're looking for](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#isWiredHeadsetOn%28%29)