# How to get ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG in OnCreate()

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, headset

So, the art of registering a broadcast receiver for ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG and actually [processing the plug in/out events](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17998116/2597758) is well figured out now.

But... my app needs to know early on at `onCreate()` whether the headset is plugged in or not (if it isn't, it should simply display a dialog and exit, as this is a headset-only app, not to be used with a speaker).

Yet, everywhere I read, registering the receiver should be done either in [onStart()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7887459) or [onResume()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7887433) -- which leave no chance for `onCreate()` to use a flag set by the receiver.

Any idea how to workaround this?

Is there a way to **poll** the headset jack?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [AudioManager's isWiredHeadsetOn()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#isWiredHeadsetOn()) to determine if a headset is plugged in, although note that as per the documentation:

> This is not a valid indication that audio playback is actually over the wired headset as audio routing depends on other conditions.

You'll also want to look at the values of `isSpeakerphoneOn()`, `isBluetoothA2dpOn()`, and `isBluetoothScoOn()` to get a better idea of what is currently enabled.

Comment: Thank you. I read about the `isWiredHeadsetOn()`'s gotchas. That is why I toyed with ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG. For some reason I missed AudioManager's `isSpeakerphoneOn()` and the other methods you mentioned, so thank you for that. In fact, it doesn't matter to me whether a wired headset is plugged in or a Bluetooth headset is routed into. As long as the audio doesn't get to the speaker, `onCreate()` should proceed.