# How do i pause MediaPlayer when the microphone is on?

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer

I noticed that if I start the Google voice search my music player doesn't pause.

How do I refer to the state when the mic is on? so i can pause the mp and start it again.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6249023/detecting-whether-a-headset-is-plugged-in-or-not see this post this might be helpful

Comment: I'm not talking about the headset's microphone.
I'm talking about the built in mic. So when the user start S Voice or Google Voice ill be able to pause the MediaPlayer object.