# How to Detect Headset Capabilities

Tags: android, headset, android-audiomanager

I know how to [detect whether a headset is plugged in](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6366238) but some headsets (e.g Samsung EHS60ANNBE) come with the PAUSE/PLAY (a.k.a KeyEvent.[KEYCODE_HEADSETHOOK](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html#KEYCODE_HEADSETHOOK)) button **only**, **without** the PREV/NEXT...

I would like to be able to detect whether the headset currently plugged into the Android device has PREV/NEXT (a.k.a KeyEvent.KEYCODE_[MEDIA_PREVIOUS](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html#KEYCODE_MEDIA_PREVIOUS)/KeyEvent.KEYCODE_[MEDIA_NEXT](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html#KEYCODE_MEDIA_NEXT)) or not.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Are you using a BroadcastReceiver? I'm guessing you are.

from Android Dev:

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if (Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON.equals(intent.getAction())) {
        //receive the key press event
        KeyEvent event = (KeyEvent)intent.getParcelableExtra(Intent.EXTRA_KEY_EVENT);
        //check the keypress
        if (KeyEvent.**** == event.getKeyCode()) {
            // Handle key press.
        }
    }
  }
}
```

[**** a link with various keypress codes](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html#KEYCODE_MEDIA_PREVIOUS)