# Keep separate volumes for speaker and headset

Tags: android, android-audiomanager

I'm currently developing a sip based application for voice and videocalls, and I have a very simple question whether it is possible to keep separate volume levels for headset and speaker, or in other words for example is the volume for headset is set at "9" and the volume for speaker is at "4", so is such a scenario possible ?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest why dont you try to detect the attachment and detachment of the headset and then set volume accordingly.

[Click this link for the stackoverflow post which discuss about the attachment and detachment of headset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6249023/detecting-whether-a-headset-is-plugged-into-an-android-device-or-not)

Comment: I know how to detect the attachment, but its the volume level that I wish to keep separate, and how possible is that scenario, that's what my question is about.

Comment: You can use use the audio manager to set the volume levels. As soon as you find an attachment of headset set volume to 9 and when detached set volume to 4. The following program shows how to set volumes              https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/blob/master/SystemServices/Volume/src/com/commonsware/android/syssvc/volume/Volumizer.java

Comment: But if I don't wish to set it manually, then is there any way within the api, that the volume automatically syncs, because there is only one stream for voice telephony but I have more than one source for the audio route.