# How to check and redirect audio between wired headset and speaker phone?

Tags: android, soundpool, android-audiomanager

I am developing a simple app , that should *toggle* between speaker phone and wired headset to play audio on a button click event. I am trying to make use of *isWiredHeadsetOn()* function, but it says that this is deprecated for Android API lvl 5 onwards. So how do I check if currently audio is playing or not through wired headset so that I can redirect it to the phone speaker?

**Note:** I start my app with the headphone plugged to the 3.5mm jack of the phone.

This is my attempt at the code so far:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_audio_re_direct);
    redirect = (Button)findViewById(R.id.redirect);
    final AudioManager audio =(AudioManager)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE);

    redirect.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(audio.isWiredHeadsetOn())
            {
                audio.setWiredHeadsetOn(false);
                audio.setSpeakerphoneOn(true);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "SpeakerPhone On", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                redirect.setText("Turn on headset");

            }
            else 
            {
                audio.setSpeakerphoneOn(false);
                audio.setWiredHeadsetOn(true);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Wired Headset On", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                redirect.setText("Turn off headset");
            }

            }

    });
        }
```

But the app is not toggling at all. Initially it detects that the wired headset is present, shows the Toast message *SpeakerPhone On* and that's it. It does not toggle between the two.

Someone please help me to make this work. Thanks.

Comment: Well, `setWiredHeadsetOn` has been deprecated since API level 5 so it won't work.

Comment: Any alternative to this? Please post if you know

Comment: You can browse the source codes for the `AudioManager` and `TelephonyManager` classes and then use Reflection to do what you want. I don' t have an example of Reflection utilising these classes but you can search SO for an example.

Answer (score 1):

you have to register a receiver for ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG intent and make a receiver class to catch that broadcast from that you can implement your own logic
 [please check this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6249023/detecting-whether-a-headset-is-plugged-into-an-android-device-or-not/6366238#6366238)

Comment: yes but how do I *enable* and *disable* the wired headset programmatically?