# Asus fonepad7, Android Audiomanager can't use setMode()

Tags: android, tablet, android-audiomanager

I'm trying to set the speaker on automatically during a phone call on my asus fonepad7 but the it seems that I'm not allowed to dot it. I'm using the code below.

```
audioManager = (AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
audioManager.setMode(audioManager.MODE_IN_COMMUNICATION);
audioManager.setSpeakerphoneOn(true);
```

give me in the Log

```
W/AudioManager﹕ setMode():Only phone app can set AudioMode during a phonecall!
W/AudioManager﹕ Not Allow setSpeakerphonOn!!!
```

The previous code works well on my Galaxy s3, so I think I have issue due to the fact I'm using a tablet instead of a phone. 
I was wondering if there's anyway to fix this (rooting the tablet and taking a specific rom ??)

Any advice or lead to fix this would be really appreciated !

Answer (score 0):

Could you try to set the MODE_IN_CALL just before setSpeakerPhoneOn ?

Comment: Already tried that, same result sadly :/
It's really annoying that you can't use that method on that device..

Comment: Ok :-(. you could try this solution http://stackoverflow.com/a/30049718/4850790 It works for me but I'm not in communication....