# Audiomanager Speaker not working

Tags: android, performance, android-audiomanager, android-phone-call

I'm trying to enable the speaker while I am in a call:

```
final AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
audioManager.setSpeakerphoneOn(true);
```

I tried to check after the `setSpeakerphoneOn()` the audiomanager and get that the speaker is still not on by asking `isSpeakerphoneOn()`

```
audioManager.isSpeakerphoneOn();
```

In my log I can see some errors that I can't understand:

```
E/AudioManager: Don't setBluetoothScoOn-PackageName: com.myapp.app  on = false
E/AudioManager: Don't setSpeakerphoneOn-PackageName: com.myapp.app  on = true
```

I can't find anything about this error in the forum.

Didn't work on devices: ZTE Z981, Huawei p9, I already tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29969030/android-force-audio-routing), and `android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS` is granted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found that `setMode()` (the current mode) before `setSpeakerphoneOn()` fixes the error on the logcat:

```
AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE); 
audioManager.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_IN_CALL);
audioManager.setSpeakerphoneOn(true);
```

Comment: `MODE_IN_CALL` is reserved to telephony stock app. Prefer `MODE_IN_COMMUNICATION` instead. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#setMode(int)

Comment: It doesn't work on huawei V/AudioManager: setMode  mode: 3
2019-09-25 19:38:30.577 1023-1560/? W/AudioService: Forbid set MODE_IN_COMMUNICATION when current mode is MODE_IN_CALL from pid=13000, uid=10409

Comment: doesn't work on the pixel 3 either after the android 10 update.

Comment: doesn't work on the pixel 2 either after the android 10 update

Comment: Samsung J4+ with Android 9 requires `MODE_IN_CALL` to get `setSpeakerphoneOn(true)` to turn on the speaker. It doesn't happen with `MODE_IN_COMMUNICATION`.

Answer (score 14):

Hi read android developer article

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html

explain it clearly

you need to set Permission: MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS in manifest

add this line in manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
```

Comment: Requires Permission: MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS.

Comment: I read. I already have this permission. It already work in all devices except ZTE.

Comment: This constant was deprecated in API level 5. Do not set audio routing directly, use setSpeakerphoneOn(), setBluetoothScoOn() methods instead.

Comment: possible it's bug in ZTE

Comment: Thanks! Was trying to set speaker phone on for a while and this fixed the issue.

Answer (score 2):

1.`setSpeakerphoneOn()` is only working on `setMode(AudioManager.MDOE_IN_CALL);`

Answer (score 1):

If your device happens to run on android 10 or later, android version could be the reason.

Since android 10, google has deprecated AudioManager.setSpeakerphoneOn api.

Look into this for reference and you can vote up that issue if you want this api back: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/141889136

If you are starting an outgoing call with `Intent.ACTION_CALL`, you still have this option:

```
intent.putExtra(TelecomManager.EXTRA_START_CALL_WITH_SPEAKERPHONE, true);
```

Comment: When targeting API 28+ this is the only thing that worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Only thing that worked for me was setting

```
audioManager.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_RINGTONE | AudioManager.MODE_IN_CALL);
audioManager.setSpeakerphoneOn(true);
```

Without AudioManager.MODE_RINGTONE it does not work ..

Thanks to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59538241/5727338)

Comment: What device and OS version you running? For me it not work on Galaxy S20, Android 11

Comment: `AudioManager.MODE_*` is not a bitfield and can't be used that way. 

`AudioManager.MODE_RINGTONE` is 1 (binary `01`) and `AudioManager.MODE_IN_CALL` is 2 (binary `10`), the resulting value is binary `11` which is 3, so your code is the same as calling `audioManager.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_IN_COMMUNICATION)` which is the recommended value for VoIP as per the official documentation.

Answer (score 0):

In case of VoIP app(self-managed call) If you want to set audio to speakerphone you need to add below 2 things

1. audioManager.setCommunicationDevice(AudioDeviceInfo.TYPE_BUILTIN_SPEAKER);
2. connection.setAudioRoute(CallAudioState.ROUTE_SPEAKER);
   inside <*T extend android.telecom.ConnectionService*> class (ConnectionService class)

   ```
    private void turnSpeakerOn(boolean turnOn, AudioManager 
    audioManager) {
       if (turnOn) {
          if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.S) {
             setAudioDevice(audioManager, 
             AudioDeviceInfo.TYPE_BUILTIN_SPEAKER);
          } else {
             audioManager.setSpeakerphoneOn(true);
          }

      sendSetAudioRouteLocalBroadcast(MyConstants.ROUTE_SPEAKER);
    } else {
      // OFF
      if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.S) {
        audioManager.clearCommunicationDevice();
      } else {
        audioManager.setSpeakerphoneOn(false);
      }
    }
   ```

}

```
  private static void setAudioDevice(AudioManager audioManager, int 
  audioType) {
      List<AudioDeviceInfo> audioDevices = 
      audioManager.getAvailableCommunicationDevices();
      for (AudioDeviceInfo device : audioDevices) {
      if (device.getType() == audioType) {
         audioManager.setCommunicationDevice(device);
         break;
      }
    }
  }
```

[2] Inside Connection class listen for local broadcast, on speakerphone button press action

// public class MyConnectionService extends ConnectionService

```
        private final BroadcastReceiver audioStateReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(final Context context, final Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getExtras() != null) {
            Connection connection = myConnection; //android.telecom.Connection class
            if (connection!= null) {
                connection.setAudioRoute(CallAudioState.ROUTE_SPEAKER);
            }
        }
    }
};
```