# Cannot hear twilio voice call on bluetooth speaker issue in android

Tags: java, android, twilio, voice

All app audios mp3 and .wav files are playing well on bluetooth speaker. But when I place an outgoing call using twilio, the voice call cannot hear on bluetooth speaker.

Comment: Might that be because the call with Twilio is deemed to be a phone call that needs a speaker and a microphone and your bluetooth speaker is just a speaker?

Comment: I am using anker bluetooth speaker which having microphone also and works as a google assistant

Comment: Are you able to use the speaker when making a regular phone call too?

Comment: Yes, speaker gets disable only while twilio calling

Comment: I spoke to one of the engineers on the Android team and they said that this isn't something that has been tested. But it would be best to look into using the audio manager to push the audio to the speaker. [This question might help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29969030/android-force-audio-routing).

Comment: Are you using a custom ROM? Does the bluetooth speaker work when you make a standard phone call with your SIM?

Comment: Not sure but this  https://github.com/twilio/audioswitch  might help you if you have not tried yet.  Also, make sure that <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" /> is set.  Also, https://github.com/twilio/voice-quickstart-android/issues/203 this might help you. I will try to reproduce if I can. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My App is now switching to Bluetooth speaker I have used audioswitch. And with this also used audioManager.setBluetoothScoOn(true); and its working fine.