# Is it possible to ignore plugged in Headset and still use phone speakers?

Tags: java, android, audio, android-audiomanager, headset

I would like to use the **Phone Speakers** while a Headset is plugged-in, instead of the Headset-Speakers.
[image]

Is it possible to do that? if yes, how can I achieve it?
I'm developing an App in Java for **Android 9**.
Detection if Headset is Plugged in works so far:

```
public class HeadsetIntentReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
private String TAG = "HeadSet";

public HeadsetIntentReceiver() {
    Log.d(TAG, "Created");
}

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if(intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG)) {
        int state = intent.getIntExtra("state", -1);
        switch(state) {
            case(0):
                Log.d(TAG, "Headset unplugged");
                break;
            case(1):
                Log.d(TAG, "Headset plugged");
                break;
            default:
                Log.d(TAG, "Error");
        }
    }
}
}
```

**EDIT:**
I tried the following Solutions, but Nothing happend:

1. [How to mute audio in headset but let it play on speaker programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20965530/how-to-mute-audio-in-headset-but-let-it-play-on-speaker-programmatically)
2. [How to disable the wired headset programmatically in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20949769/how-to-disable-the-wired-headset-programmatically-in-java)

   Thanks in Advance for any helpful advice.

---

(Please don't answer "Unplug the Headset")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for [AudioManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager)

Attach `AUDIO_SERVICE` to AudioManager, set AudioManager as `MODE_IN_COMMUNICATION` and then set your speaker phone on. You can use the speaker as if you were talking on the phone.

```
AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
audioManager.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_IN_COMMUNICATION);
audioManager.setSpeakerphoneOn(true);
```

**Remember to restore it after use.**
for example,

```
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    audioManager.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_NORMAL);
    audioManager.setSpeakerphoneOn(false);
}
```

Comment: Hi Fleta, unfortunately, the solution doesn't seem to work. I called myself with another phone while a working headset was on the phone. The sound only came from the headset :/

Comment: Just in case it is necessary to know: The Call was made via VoIP.

Comment: Hi Michael, sorry for incorrect answer. Can you try again by changing the mode `MODE_IN_COMMUNICATION` to `MODE_CURRENT` or `MODE_IN_CALL` ?

Comment: Hi Fleta, Nothing changed after trying These different modes :/. Still same behavior.

Comment: I discovered, that this Code must be executed, after the Call has been accepted instead of before. So basically, this answer is correct.

Comment: @Michael i am facing this weird problem making a phone call but the speaker is not turning on but how can we detect if an outgoing call is connected?