# Normal Phone Call with Headset plugged possible?

Tags: android, audio, phone-call, android-audiomanager

I'm facing a Problem, related to my Question: [Is it possible to ignore plugged in Headset and still use phone speakers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59190823/is-it-possible-to-ignore-plugged-in-headset-and-still-use-phone-speakers/59191154)
I used the same code as in the linked question. The only change here is that I use the `PhoneStateListener` to intercept when a call is answered and respond to it. This Code is executed, if a Call get's answered:

```
AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) _context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
audioManager.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_IN_CALL);
```

If I add `audioManager.setSpeakerphoneOn(true);` to it, the loudspeakers are activated (what I don't want)
Nothing happens if I change the `AudioManager` Mode from `AudioManager.MODE_IN_CALL` to `AudioManager.MODE_IN_COMMUNICATION`

**My Problem** is, that I can't make an "normal" Phone Call, while my Headset is plugged in.
So far I played around with `AudioManager` and the `setMode()` function of it.
Unfortunately, the only thing I managed to do was to make a phone call over the loudspeakers. But this is not the desired goal.

Can anyone help me with this?