# Detect when music starts playing (or related events) without polling

Tags: android

My goal is to detect when music starts playing on the device. In my case I want to launch volume controls on an Android Wear device but that's irrelevant for the question.

I know there is [`AudioManager.isMusicActive()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#isMusicActive%28%29) but it requires polling. I would rather listen for a broadcast without keeping a service alive indefinitely.

The other alternative would be to listen for headphones being plugged in but apparently [`Intent.ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG) is only delivered to dynamic receivers as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6249023/detecting-whether-a-headset-is-plugged-into-an-android-device-or-not/6366238#6366238) answer suggests.

I'm a bit clueless here. How can I listen for any audio related events without constant polling?

Comment: Did you solve your problem?

Comment: I just used a notification listener in the end.

Comment: Can you please explain it a bit more? I am trying to do something similar for a research project that logs data of how people use the sound of their phone (how much hours, what volume, with/without headphones). I was afraid that I had to check every X minutes, but if there is a way to avoid that it would be great!

Comment: I use a `NotificationListenerService` and check if a notification of the music app, e.g. Google Play Music, is shown.

Comment: But not all (popular) music players create a notification when playing... so this is probably not working all the time. If I play a song in Spotify for example but keep the app open no notification is created so your notificationListener isn't working and you don't know if the music is playing or not...

Comment: I know. I didn't find a better way.

Comment: Ok. Thanks, I probably won't either...