# Static broadcast not working ANDROID

Tags: android, static, broadcastreceiver, android-broadcast

This is my receiver file

`package com.example.tony.headsetplug;`

```
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MusicIntentReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.i("Tag","got receiver");
    }
}
```

I am trying to implement a static broadcast for plugging in the headset, my manifest file where the static broadcast is defined.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

    <receiver
        android:name=".MusicIntentReceiver"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.headset_plug" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>





</application>
```

It's not working, not even showing a broadcast received.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of `ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG` is `"android.intent.action.HEADSET_PLUG"` (note upper case letters in it). Check the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG) as well.

***p.s.***: in addition, you'll have to register the receiver programmatically (check for instance [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6249023/detecting-whether-a-headset-is-plugged-into-an-android-device-or-not/6366238#6366238)), e.g.:

```
IntentFilter receiverFilter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG);
HeadsetStateReceiver receiver = new HeadsetStateReceiver();
registerReceiver( receiver, receiverFilter );
```

Comment: Thank you, when it's registered in the main activity or any activity it works while the activity is running. I still want the broadcast to be received, even when the activity is closed. Is that possible? Or for this, should I run a service in background ?

Comment: Yes, use a service in this case (start it _STICKY_, see http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#START_STICKY). What I forgot to mention: use `unregisterReceiver(...)` in `onDestroy()` because registering a BroadcastReceiver twice causes an exception. **p.s.**: using a LocalBroadcastManager can have some advantages (see http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/LocalBroadcastManager.html); example here: http://www.intertech.com/Blog/using-localbroadcastmanager-in-service-to-activity-communications/

Comment: I'd be happy if you could up-vote my question - or accept it, if you think it was the most useful answer ;)

Answer (score 1):

From the official API documentation on [AudioManager.ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG):

> Broadcast Action: Wired Headset plugged in or unplugged. **You cannot receive this through components declared in manifests**, only by explicitly registering for it with Context.registerReceiver().
>
> The intent will have the following extra values:
>
> - state - 0 for unplugged, 1 for plugged.
> - name - Headset type, human readable string
> - microphone - 1 if headset has a microphone, 0 otherwise

This should explain, why it's not working properly when defined as static. I think since music applications usally rely on this broadcast, it makes no sense to receieve such a broadcast when the user is not actually listening to music or doing anything audio related.

**Edit:**

What if you want to launch your Music app when headphones are plugged, but your activity is not running?

Consider using a background service, which doens't do much except registering the receiver which handles the ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG. In order to start your servic in case the device is (re-)booted, you can add a static receiver listening to ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED, which launches the service.

Btw: If you are wondering whether you can start your service as soon as your app gets installed, you can't. At least according to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8531926/how-to-start-a-service-when-apk-is-installed-for-the-first-time).

Hope this helps.

Comment: But what if, I want to play music automatically when I plug in my headphones, the music app is not running(or the activity)

Answer (score -1):

You have to register the receiver by code and it is a must:

stackoverflow.com/questions/6249023/detecting-whether-a-headset-is-plugged-into-an-android-device-or-not

If u wanna your listener to be on always, you should listen for system boot intent and register in that listener.