# Doze and App Standby mode in Android 6.0

Tags: android, chat, voip, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-doze-and-standby

Google introduced Doze and App Standby mode with Android 6.0 OS.
Device will enter in `Doze` mode if device is unplugged and unused for some amount of time and if application stays inactive for some amount of time, that app goes in `StandBy` mode (Correct me if I am wrong).

> 1. Can we (developer) know, device entered in `Doze` mode or application entered in `StandBy` mode? How?

http://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby.html#whitelisting-cases In this link, Google says that `Voip` or `Chat` or `Calling` application will still work when device is in `Doze` mode.

> 2. How OS will come to know that this is `Voip` or `chat` or `Calling` app, so i will keep it awake in `Doze` mode too.?
> 3. What callback I need to register to complete maintenance task when application is out of `Doze` mode.?

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes, you can get informed of idle mode changes, by listening for DEVICE_IDLE_MODE_CHANGED intents, see: [Android M listening to android.os.action.DEVICE_IDLE_MODE_CHANGED](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31559698/android-m-listening-to-android-os-action-device-idle-mode-changed)
2. You will need to whitelist your app, details here: https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby.html#support_for_other_use_cases
3. Same as for 1.

This page is also a really useful explanation of doze mode and how to test your app's handling of idle state: https://newcircle.com/s/post/1739/2015/06/12/diving-into-android-m-doze