# Broadcast Receiver when App is closed

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I don't know how to detect when a user plug his headset in the phone when the app is closed or killed. I can do this when the app is running but i want to be able to do this when its closed. I think I have to make a Broadcast Receiver into my service but I don't know how to do it...
Thanks for help,
A french developper who is trying to speak english

EDIT: I am on Android Studio

Comment: Which platform are you developing for? Android or iOS?

Comment: I'm going to assume Android

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Detecting whether a headset is plugged into an Android device or not.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6249023/detecting-whether-a-headset-is-plugged-into-an-android-device-or-not)