# How can i check if the microphone in my android device is plugged in the os gui?

Tags: android, hardware, sensors, microphone

I am trying to build app that show if some of your device hardware is not plugged properly. 
For example if your camera sensor is unplugged than the camera app will disappear from your device apps list and you will not be able to use it. 
I want to know if there is a way to know using software only if the microphone is not plugged

Note - if i cant hear no sound it can be because the microphone broken and not because he got unplugged

ONE MORE THING
im not talking about headset state because i know you can know if there is headset and if it is with mic or not

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Detecting whether a headset is plugged into an Android device or not.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6249023/detecting-whether-a-headset-is-plugged-into-an-android-device-or-not)

Comment: Additionally: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG