# Detect plugged & unplugged event on headphone jack in Xamarin.Android

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android, headset, headphones

I'm trying to find a way to detect the plugged/unplugged event on headphone Jack in Xamarin.Android. Is there a way to do it in this? and if it is, how can I implement that functionality?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try to convert java code into c#, for example:

```
[BroadcastReceiver(Enabled = true)]
[IntentFilter(new[] { Android.Content.Intent.ActionHeadsetPlug })]
public class MyBroadcastReceiver : BroadcastReceiver
{

    bool Microphone_Plugged_in = false;
    public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        String action = intent.Action;
        int iii;
        if (Intent.ActionHeadsetPlug.Equals(action))
        {
            iii = intent.GetIntExtra("state", -1);
            if (iii == 0)
            {
                Microphone_Plugged_in = false;
                Toast.MakeText(context, "microphone not plugged in", ToastLength.Long).Show();
            }
            if (iii == 1)
            {
                Microphone_Plugged_in = true;
                Toast.MakeText(context, "microphone plugged in", ToastLength.Long).Show();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And usage:

```
BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver;
IntentFilter receiverFilter;
```

and initialize value in method `OnCreate` of your activity:

```
broadcastReceiver = new MyBroadcastReceiver();
receiverFilter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ActionHeadsetPlug);
```

And `RegisterReceiver` and `UnregisterReceiver` by override method `OnResume` and `OnPause`

```
    protected override void OnResume()
    {
        base.OnResume();
        RegisterReceiver(broadcastReceiver, receiverFilter);
    }

    protected override void OnResume()
    {
        base.OnResume();

        IntentFilter receiverFilter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ActionHeadsetPlug);
        RegisterReceiver(broadcastReceiver, receiverFilter);
    }
```

For more, you can check thread: [Detecting whether a headset is plugged into an Android device or not.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6249023/detecting-whether-a-headset-is-plugged-into-an-android-device-or-not/6366238#6366238)

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/broadcast-receivers

Answer (score 0):

You have to write the code in xamarin.android file. Use broadcast receiver for implementation. In onReceive() you will get the intent as Intent.ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG.

Following pseudo code might help you,

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
   BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver;
   boolean Microphone_Plugged_in = false;
   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
      broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
         @Override
         public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            final String action = intent.getAction();
            int iii;
            if (Intent.ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG.equals(action)) {
               iii = intent.getIntExtra("state", -1);
               if (iii == 0) {
                  Microphone_Plugged_in = false;
                  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "microphone not plugged in", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
               }
               if (iii == 1) {
                  Microphone_Plugged_in = true;
                  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "microphone plugged in",
                  Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
               }
            }
         }
      };
      IntentFilter receiverFilter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG);
      registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, receiverFilter);
   }
}
```

Comment: The name '@Override' does not exist in the current context.

Comment: Your solution seems to be for Java, please help with C# as well

Answer (score 0):

```
[BroadcastReceiver(Enabled = true)]
[IntentFilter(new[] { Android.Content.Intent.ActionHeadsetPlug })]
public class HeadsetPlugBroadcastReceiver : BroadcastReceiver
{
    public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        String action = intent.Action;
        if (Intent.ActionHeadsetPlug.Equals(action))
        {
            var state = intent.GetIntExtra("state", -1);
            if (state == 0)
            {
                // Plugged out
            }
            if (state == 1)
            {
                // Plugged in
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `var broadcastReceiver = new HeadsetPlugBroadcastReceiver();  var receiverFilter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ActionHeadsetPlug);  
RegisterReceiver(broadcastReceiver, receiverFilter);`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).