# how to stop video when the user eject the earphones - flutter

Tags: flutter

Please, I wanna know how to prevent or stop video when the user eject the earphones from the device.
Flutter

I tried to find a package for that. but i didn't found any package or solution

Comment: Please add some code to show what you have for controlling the video already.

Answer (score 0):

you can listen on the headset events with this [package](https://pub.dev/packages/headset_connection_event)
and inside the listener check if the event is `DISCONNECT` then pause the video through `videoController.pause()`

Additional ref links:

[Detecting whether a headset is plugged into an Android device or not.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6249023/detecting-whether-a-headset-is-plugged-into-an-android-device-or-not)