# Is it possible to be notified of incoming bluetooth connections and receive the incoming UUID?

Tags: android, bluetooth, connection, broadcastreceiver

So I know that in Android I can get an incoming connection by simply using `listenUsingRfcommWithServiceRecord(String, UUID).` but I'm just wondering if there is a way to set up a `BraodcastReceiver` or something that gets notified every time a device connects via bluetooth to our phone and get the UUID out of the incoming Intent. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can monitor the bluetooth connection (listening to Broadcast action : ACTION_ACL_CONNECTED) and notify that the connection. Also checkout

[How to programmatically tell if a Bluetooth device is connected? (Android 2.2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4715865/how-to-programmatically-tell-if-a-bluetooth-device-is-connected-android-2-2)

Finally checkout [Bluetooth Device](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothDevice.html) from the Android Docs to get more information about it.

Comment: Alrighty, that is one mystery solved, but how do I get a hold of the UUID though. In my broadcast receiver I don't want to mess with connections from another app, so I want to compare the incoming UUID with that of my app before doing anything.