# Android  bluetooth code working fine on 2.2 but not on 2.3 or 2.3.3

Tags: android, bluetooth, ioexception

i am using code to make Bluetooth connection,

```
public void run() 
{
    try 
    {




        Method m = mBluetoothDevice.getClass().getMethod("createRfcommSocket", new Class[] {int.class});
        mBluetoothSocket = (BluetoothSocket) m.invoke(mBluetoothDevice, 1);


       // mBluetoothSocket = mBluetoothDevice.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(applicationUUID);
        mBluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();

        mBluetoothSocket.connect();





    }
    catch (IOException eConnectException) 
    {
        Log.d(TAG, "CouldNotConnectToSocket", eConnectException);
         closeSocket(mBluetoothSocket);
         return;
    } catch (SecurityException e) {

        Log.d(TAG, "CouldNotConnectToSocket", e);
        closeSocket(mBluetoothSocket);
    } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {

        Log.d(TAG, "CouldNotConnectToSocket", e);
        closeSocket(mBluetoothSocket);
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "CouldNotConnectToSocket", e);
        closeSocket(mBluetoothSocket);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "CouldNotConnectToSocket", e);
        closeSocket(mBluetoothSocket);
    } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "CouldNotConnectToSocket", e);
        closeSocket(mBluetoothSocket);
    }
}
```

it is working fine on a Karbonn device which is android 2.2 and when i try same code on Samsung Galaxy Y and Sony Ericson Xperia mini then it does not work...
What can be the issue..Kindly assist...

Comment: elaborate "doesn't work" with error logs...

Comment: No error and after 10-12 sec ACTION_ACL_DISCONNECTED event fired...

Answer (score 0):

Did u set the permissions in the manifest?

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"/>
```

And whats exactly your exception?

EDIT:
according to this
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothDevice.html#ACTION_ACL_DISCONNECTED
it's a low level exception that shouldnt occur.

[How to programmatically tell if a Bluetooth device is connected? (Android 2.2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4715865/how-to-programmatically-tell-if-a-bluetooth-device-is-connected-android-2-2)
Does this help you?

Comment: these event i have already captured, main problem is that code is working fine on Karbon (2.2) but working on samsung galaxy y(2.3)..