# get bluetooth device leave the connection

Tags: android, bluetooth, range

I have a bluetooth device , I want to know how to obtain the method when connected Bluetooth device is out of range 
like code

//if bluetooth is Not in the range of connection
{

}

Please give me some solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check whether a bluetooth device is connected or not you can use intent filters to listen to the ACTION_ACL_CONNECTED, ACTION_ACL_DISCONNECT_REQUESTED, and ACTION_ACL_DISCONNECTED broadcasts. For more details please check this post [How to programmatically tell if a Bluetooth device is connected? (Android 2.2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4715865/how-to-programmatically-tell-if-a-bluetooth-device-is-connected-android-2-2)

Answer (score 0):

There is no internal method like `DeviceNotInRange() {}` hence you need to work it out by creating your customized method. You need to create a method that keep searching on a regular interval and when device is not in range, you can raise an Alert or sound for intimation.