# Bluetooth pairing in Android. Event to be called when connection is lost

Tags: android, bluetooth

I am trying to pair an android app with a bluetooth device, I need to know which event is to be called when the connection with this bluetooth device is lost.

Answer (score 1):

You can use BroadCast receiver and capture the ACTION_ACL_DISCONNECTED event.
See here for more details:
[How to programmatically tell if a Bluetooth device is connected? (Android 2.2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4715865/how-to-programmatically-tell-if-a-bluetooth-device-is-connected-android-2-2)