# How to programmatically check connection state of a Bluetooth device in Android?

Tags: android, bluetooth

I can enumerate the paired `Bluetooth` devices, and I need to check their current connection state on app startup.

But, I found no way of getting the connection state ?!

Here are some efforts I've tried but failed:

1. android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice

It has the method to get the bond state of the remote device, and possible values for the bond state are: `BOND_NONE`, `BOND_BONDING`, `BOND_BONDED`. But it's not the connection state.

2. android.bluetooth.BluetoothProfile

The method can be used to get the connection state, but the `BluetoothProfile` object must be obtained first.

```
public abstract int getConnectionState (BluetoothDevice device);
```

As describe in doc: "*Clients should call getProfileProxy(Context, BluetoothProfile.ServiceListener, int), to get the Profile Proxy.*", it can ONLY be retrieve in a `ServiceListener` called when state changes.

What if I query the state on startup without any state changes happen yet?

3. android.bluetooth.BluetoothManager

It provides a method:

```
public int getConnectionState (BluetoothDevice device, int profile);
```

But it cannot be used to detect connection state of a `Bluetooth` speaker, as the profile argument only accepts `GATT` or `GATT_SERVER` (for low energy device), other profiles (`HEADSET`, `HEALTH`, `A2DP`) are not supported.

4. android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter

It provides a method:

```
public int getProfileConnectionState (int profile);
```

This function can be used to check whether the local `Bluetooth` adapter is connected to any remote device for a specific profile. It can be used to check a specified profile. But it cannot be used to check a given device.

Does anyone know how to get the connection state of a given `Bluetooth` device?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you found any answer for this?

Comment: Struck on this for two days help could be greatly appreciated.Did you found any solution for this. I want to check the Bluetooth gatt connection state if is connected then need to wait until it moves to disconnected state but i used the getConnectionState() it throws exception.

Answer (score 1):

See the notes in the answer from similar question [How to programmatically tell if a Bluetooth device is connected? (Android 2.2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4715865/how-to-programmatically-tell-if-a-bluetooth-device-is-connected-android-2-2):

- There is no way to retrieve a list of connected devices at application startup. The Bluetooth API does not allow you to QUERY, instead it allows you to listen to CHANGES.
- A hoaky work around to the above problem would be to retrieve the list of all known/paired devices... then trying to connect to each one (to determine if you're connected).
  Alternatively, you could have a background service watch the Bluetooth API and write the device states to disk for your application to use at a later date.