# How to implement a bluetooth broadcastreceiver?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-bluetooth

I need to catch bluetooth data from another applications (bluetooth messengers), analyze message and ask user to send SMS. How to realize it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4716715/1199408

Comment: @GiorgosOikonomou, this is catching connecting and disconnecting. I need catch data.

Comment: There is a sample from google with Bluetooth chart. You will get an idea there. https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/25b6aed7b2e01ce7bdc0dfa1a79eaf009ad178fe/samples/BluetoothChat
Basically you need to oepn a socket and read the data

Comment: @GiorgosOikonomou thank you