# How to check if Bluetooth Scanner is connected or not In Android

Tags: android, bluetooth, barcode-scanner

I'm working on an App that requires bluetooth scanner. What I want is, I want to show a scanner icon on top of my App, whenever a bluetooth scanner is connected, that icon will change its color. I currently don't have bluetooth scanner with myself. How do I check if the scanner is connected. I've done the same task for internet connection. But How to check for a scanner? Is there any scanner class just like there is ConnectivityManager for checking internet connection.

Comment: you should have searched google first, atleast once .https://www.google.co.in/search?q=check+if+bluetooth+is+connected+android&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=9457VuXMEpCfugTW05awCg

Comment: Try this. [How to programmatically tell if a Bluetooth device is connected?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4715865/how-to-programmatically-tell-if-a-bluetooth-device-is-connected-android-2-2)