# Android: Determine if Bluetooth is connected to any devices or not

Tags: android, bluetooth

Hello everyone is there a way to check if Android phone is connected to any Bluetooth devices programmatically?

Should there be a state such as `Bluetooth_state == Bluetooth_connected` OR `Bluetooth_state == Bluetooth_disconnected` OR `Bluetooth.isConnected()`. The goal is to recognise if Phone's Bluetooth is connected to any device or not.

Comment: At least somebody suggest me something. Please.

Comment: Well, at least you can check the bluetooth earphone `BluetoothProfile.STATE_CONNECTED == bluetoothAdapter.getProfileConnectionState(BluetoothProfile.HEADSET)` ...

Answer (score 3):

If you only want to check that device is connected or not upon launch, try `mBluetoothAdapter.getProfileConnectionState()`; should work for you.

```
 public static boolean isBluetoothHeadsetConnected() {
 BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
 return mBluetoothAdapter != null && mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()
       && mBluetoothAdapter.getProfileConnectionState(BluetoothHeadset.HEADSET) == BluetoothHeadset.STATE_CONNECTED;
}//BluetoothHeadset.A2DP can also be used for Stereo media devices.
```

Don't forget to ask for permission in manifest as well.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
```

[Original Answer by @jobbert](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41181469/1149398)